# Place DrawerLayout on top of other layouts without overlaying them

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I'm a bit confused here. I want to place my toolbar on top, then the navigation drawer in the middle and the bottom toolbar in the background. So hierarchy would look like this

```
RelativeLayout
--Top toolbar (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)
--Navigation drawer (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout)
------Bottom toolbar (LinearLayout)
```

[image]

But I realized I couldn't do it, because the navigation drawer doesn't have a bottom gravity attribute for the bottom toolbar. So I changed the main RelativeLayout for a FrameLayout and put my elements in order as elements stacks in a FrameLayout.

```
FrameLayout
-- Top toolbar
-- Navigation Drawer
-- Bottom toolbar
```

What happens is obviously is that the navigation drawer overlaps the bottom toolbar and I can't interact with it at all.

So my question is: **how can I still have access to the bottom toolbar without changing the order?** How should I organize my layout to achieve the desired effect?

I know I should place the navigation drawer on top but then I can't see the toolbar and I have to.

Also if anyone knows why, the dark fading when drawer opens up doesn't appear for some reason. It used to though.

**EDIT:**
I changed the FrameLayout for a RelativeLayout and used layout_below as suggested, but my bottom LinearLayout doesn't appear. Here's my .xml file (simplified a bit):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <!-- TOP TOOLBAR -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/top_toolbar_container">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/top_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- NAVIGATION DRAWER -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_toolbar_container">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <!-- BOTTOM TOOLBAR -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/bot_toolbar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_below="@id/nav_drawer">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I was just trying to comment on your other post. Editing it would've bumped it to the top of the active queue, btw. No need to delete and repost. Anyhoo, don't use a `FrameLayout`. In your `RelativeLayout` setup, `layout_below` the `DrawerLayout` under the `Toolbar`, and put the `LinearLayout` at the bottom of the `DrawerLayout`'s content `View`. If you need more specifics, post your layout XML.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try it! I tried editing but it wouldn't bump...

Comment: @MikeM. I did what you suggested but now the bottom toolbar doesn't appear

Comment: The bottom "toolbar" needs to go at the bottom of the `DrawerLayout`'s content `View`. A regular `DrawerLayout` takes two `View`s: the first one listed is the content `View` that the drawer opens over, and the second is the drawer `View` itself. So, e.g., in yours, you might add a `RelativeLayout` first thing inside the `DrawerLayout`, and stick the `LinearLayout` in there, aligned to the bottom.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes perfect you just fixed all of my problems! Bottom toolbar appears and I can click it, and the dark fading is back. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeM. I just realised that the animation of the 3 lines icon becoming an arrow doesnt work anymore do you know how to fix this?

Comment: It's `ActionBarDrawerToggle` that does that. It could be due to a few different things, depending on your setup, but a common cause of that is forgetting to call `syncState()` on the toggle after it's initialized.

Comment: Oh, actually, if you can see the hamburger, but it just doesn't animate, then it's more likely that you forgot to add it as a `DrawerListener` on the `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: @MikeM. syncState was there and DrawerListener too. Any idea what else might be causing this?